# CouchDB cookie authentication with HTTPS

Tags: curl, https, couchdb

I configured my CouchDB with HTTPS using exactly the instruction given in the documentation (only that I changed the ssl port to 6161). And I created two admins. Then when I tried to log in using cookie authentication like the following:

```
curl -kX POST https://localhost:6161/_session \
   -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
   -d 'name=admin&password=admin'
```

The username and password are correct, as I can login using the `-u` option of curl. But I always got `unauthorized` error. I am not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out what I should do in this case. I need to combine basic authentication and cookie authentication to be able to log in.

```
curl -kX POST -u admin:admin https://localhost:6161/_session \
     -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
     -d 'name=admin&password=admin'
```

Maybe it is because I set `require_valid_user = true`, and cookie authentication is one of the REST API, while basic authentication is part of the HTTP protocol, and the flag above affects in the HTTP level.

But now there is still the problem: do I need to provide twice the login information each time to do cookie authentication? How about I provide one login for basic authentication and another login for cookie authentication? Could this be a threat for the system?

Comment: You can’t add two conflicting credential pairs :)

Comment: @JanLehnardt I am not fully understanding what you mean. But this is the only way I found out which works. I need to provide log in information using `-u` option to do every request unless I have an AuthSession cookie, so to get the log in cookie I need to provide the log in using the `-u` option and in the body of the message.

Comment: What I meant is this: CouchDB has a number of authentication schemes that it goes through. By default these are, in that order: oauth, basic auth, cookie auth. If you send a request with both a cookie and basic auth info, CouchDB will run oauth first, decide there is no oauth info, drop to the next one, basic auth, which it sees present and then either grants or denies access. the session cookie will not even be looked at if basic auth allowed or denied the request to proceed

Comment: @JanLehnardt I would agree with your explanation, but the thing is, I cannot get it work if I don't provide the login using basic auth, I always get "authentication required". And strangely if I do what I gave in my answer, I WILL get authenticated and an `AuthSession` cookie back, which I can use later without basic auth. So again, I am still very confused. But thank you for your explanation!

Comment: For what its worth, i have the same issue with couchdb2.0: https POST _session always results in unauthorized 
```
HOST="http://127.0.0.1:5984"
curl -X POST $HOST/_session \
       -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
       -d 'name=testlocal442&password=test'
{"ok":true,"name":"testlocal442","roles":["foo", "bar"]}

HOST="https://127.0.0.1:6984"
curl -kvX POST $HOST/_session \
       -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
       -d 'name=testlocal442&password=test'
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Name or password is incorrect."}
```